# rmarkdown ggplot does not show chinese characters correctly

Tags: r, r-markdown

I use yihui's Rmarkdown template, which is CTeX documents, in Rmarkdown. The Chinese character in ggplot does not show correctly. Specifically, they are shown as "....".

- I have already read [Encoding of multibyte characters](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/), but still not fix this problem.
- I also tried `showtext` package and use `showtext.auto()`, still not work